# Conexión Base de Datos MariaDb con VB.NET

Tags: base-de-datos

explico la situación, estoy elaborando una App de escritorio con `VB.NET`, localmente al conectarme con `MySql` no tengo mayor problemas en la cadena de conexión, sin embargo, cuando quiero conectarme remotamente a la BD de mi proveedor de Hosting resulta que tiene `MariaBd` como manejador de BD; hago la conexión desde mi Pc con `WorkBench` y no tengo problemas de conexión a la BD de `MariaBd`, lo cual me dice que si está en línea (habilitado para conexiones remotas).

Sin embargo al cambiar el HOST de localhost (local) por la IP publica me da el siguiente error: `No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos.` y he buscado mucho cómo solucionar mi problema y no he podido, les paso la cadena de conexión (con datos ficticios) de cómo la tengo estructurada:

```
server=193.203.166.125;
port=3306;
user id=u484;
password=0psw1;
database=u484;
sslmode=Disabled;
persistsecurityinfo=False
```

Ojala alguien me pueda ayudar o guiar, porque aquí tengo atorado mi proyecto; mientras sigo avanzando localmente, pero si requiero conectarme remotamente.. sino estoy en serios problemas..

Cabe mencionar que también se hicieron pruebas con PHP de conexión a la BD y no dio problemas, lo cual me indica que puede ser algún problema directamente de Vb.NET

> NOTA:
> Estoy usando para conectarme mysql-connector-net-8.2.0.msi
> Estoy importando MySql.Data.MySqlClient en mi clase de conexión.